# Sentence Transformers - IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, sentence-transformers

I am using DistilBERT from sentence_transformers library on kaggle, but when I import my model and try to encode a sentence with it :

```
modelB = SentenceTransformer('../input/sentence-transformer-models/stsb-distillbert-base')

a = ['This framework generates embeddings for each input sentence',
    'Sentences are passed as a list of string.',
    'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.']

modelB.encode(a)
```

I got the following error :

> IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)

Comment: I guess the problem is due to the model, cause changing the model to `paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2` leads to perfect execution.

Comment: The problem is that when I run it locally it doesn t give any error.

Comment: The model is saved on your local machine? Where you are running the code? @Khadija